# How to reduce a fraction within a class?

Tags: python

I'm trying to reduce(self) to return fractions which have the lowest value.

This is the code I have:

```
class fraction:
    def __init__(self,numerator,denominator):
        self.numerator = numerator
        self.denominator = denominator
        self.reduce()
    def get_numerator(self):
        return self.numerator

    def get_denominator(self):
        return self.denominator

    def reduce(self):
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.numerator) + "/" + str(self.denominator)
```

And this is the test code:

```
# y = fraction(2*7,7*2)
# z = fraction(13,14)
# a = fraction(13*2*7,14)
# print(x)
# print(y)
# print(z)
# print(a)
```

I don't want to use math.gcd or import fractions but rather do it by hand.

I'm not sure what to try without these operators. Would it be perhaps a while loop?

Comment: Have you tried reading how to implement Euclid's GCD algorithm? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm Simplest GCD algorithm I know of.

Comment: You need a GCD operation.  You can either use `math.gcd` or reinvent the wheel on your own.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/843953)
|
[Open letter to students with homework problems](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/39188)
|
[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)

Comment: There are two separate questions here. If you want to ask how to compute a GCD, the use-case isn't really relevant. If you want to ask how to use the GCD to reduce a fraction, you should just assume for the purposes of the question that you are using `math.gcd`; you can always replace that with your home-brew `gcd` function later.

Answer (score -1):

You can implement `reduce()` using [Greatest Common Divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor). As @NickODell said [in comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74466397/how-to-reduce-a-fraction-within-a-class/74466547#comment131454649_74466397) this GCD algorithm is described in [Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) Wiki. And implemented in my code below:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVJRboMwDP3nFF6lSYRFYy2rKk1C2k1QgEAjQaiC0UQvzxIokMC6fIBjv2c/O771eG1kNAxZxdoWCsUyFI388kCfnBeQJEIKTBK/5VVBQXY1VwwbRXVUNrWQ5kImvDkG9r6gIF4ZLsRia5B1c2GK513GfeItgkqOyZJzVGVVVxw7JTciXK5V6j@2rWgEfLfIUGQ11wPL14xZ7jMKqZXl5yoqDim8xPCxes0xQN1sSoHBK6TbumwV@mh7o08Uu/HqGqD/@5Huik9FFlephYws04Gble7SkWfPG4YxlM8fdgpbu9SieqzSH2NHtRFC4A0O4UF/l5gjyut1E/PK@qfgQi/BiXh323uM6PGTeMz1BQZs/DclJPr9bNxng83GSjpTiM6EDMMv)

```py
class fraction:
    def __init__(self, numerator, denominator):
        self.numerator = numerator
        self.denominator = denominator
        self.reduce()

    def get_numerator(self):
        return self.numerator

    def get_denominator(self):
        return self.denominator

    @staticmethod
    def gcd(a, b):
        while b != 0:
            a, b = b, a % b
        return a

    def reduce(self):
        if self.numerator == 0 or self.denominator == 0:
            return
        g = self.gcd(self.numerator, self.denominator)
        self.numerator //= g
        self.denominator //= g

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.numerator) + "/" + str(self.denominator)

y = fraction(2*7,7*2)
z = fraction(13,14)
a = fraction(13*2*7,14)
print(y)
print(z)
print(a)
print(fraction(15, 35))
```

Output:

```
1/1
13/14
13/1
3/7
```

Comment: Don't write the code for the OP.